# How to enable network adapter in centOS7 minimal?

Tags: centos-7, wired-networking

While installing centOS 7 minimal, I missed enabling network.

Now, I am unable to connect to the network (unable to ping or install packages using yum to be precise).

How can I enable the network settings so that I can connect to the network and install packages using yum?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit the file from the below location.

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp<number>` 
Change the `ONBOOT` option to `YES` and restart network service.

`service network restart`

This will enable the network whenever VM is brought up.

To know the network status use the `nmcli d` command `STATE` column output.

Comment: I cannot find any text editor on centos minimal. nither nano nor vim.

Comment: please add vim just using yum install.

Comment: Realized that I should type `vi` instead of `vim`.

Answer (score 5):

May be you just need to bring the network interface up, so the command is

```
ifup enp0s3
```

Comment: Do you know what the s would be for in 'enp0s3' I assume it's 'ethernet port 0' but don't know what s3 refers to?

Comment: @RobertHoughton `s3` in your example is slot 3. `[P<domain>]p<bus>s<slot>[f<function>][d<dev_id>]` [Redhat Docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-understanding_the_predictable_network_interface_device_names)

Comment: As I could not find any text editor on the CentOS minimal, this has been the working answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have DHCP available on the network, you can also run `dhclient` and it will attempt to configure DHCP on all available interfaces.